SQL - How to get the value from one column based on comparing values from other columns
I have a table with following format:



PartRef
Part
Date




123401
123401
22072024


123401
123402
24072024


234501
234501
20062024


345601
345601
10052024



I need to check if the value from column PartRef ist existing in the column Part and then extract the corresponding value from column Date to a new column.
So in above example for PartRef=123401 it should return 22072024 for the first and the second row.
The result should look like this:



PartRef
Part
Date
RelDate




123401
123401
22072024
22072024


123401
123402
24072024
22072024


234501
234501
20062024
20062024


345601
345601
10052024
10052024



How to achieve that?
I already tried with some subqueries, using EXIST and also IN but I was not able to retrieve the correct date for the specific rows.

If part is unique you can just self-join. select orig.partRef, orig.part, orig.date, coalesce(rel.RelDate, orig.date) as RelDate from your_table orig left join your_table rel on orig.partRef = rel.part

Can you add some more sample data, e.g. a partref with 3 different parts, all with different dates.

You should use self join here, Something like this
Select a.Date 
from TableName as a
join TableName as b on a.PartRef = b.Part


On the right track, but you've got a typo that'll be confusing. a.date should be b.date as RelDate

@Error_2646 thanks but its self join on same table so i guess it doesnt really matters a.date or b.date

That is not correct. The point of the self join is to get data associated with a different record on the same table. As currently written the self join does not achieve anything. Check out Elemental's answer, that is correct.

It is possible to join a table to itself in SQL using syntax like this:
Select A.Partref,B.Part,A.date,B.date as RelDate 
from PartTable A,PartTable B where A.Part=B.PartRef

Also you can rename the columns using as (as I have above). A query of this type  should serve your criteria well and should preform better than a subquery.
This is probably a good place to consider using a view to simplify future queries.

Why the old join syntax? JOIN has been around for a couple decades now.
